# How to find xpath for <p> with no class or unique identifier

Tags: xpath

```
<p>
<span>Welcome<span>
Hello welcome.
<p>
<p>
<span>Welcome!!!<span>
Good morning
<p>
```

Comment: Without further details : `//p`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the FirePath plugin that mozilla has.
Or if not then for the following code

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
<span>Welcome<span>
Hello welcome.
<p>
<p>
<span>Welcome!!!<span>
Good morning
<p>
</body>
</html>
```

The xpath for second **p** element will be : html/body/p[2]

For the span within it: html/body/p[2]/span

Answer (score 0):

Use // slash to find all the elements present on the DOM with start with p tag

`//p` will return you all element present on the DOM in p tag

Hope it will help you :)